# Template and typename

Tags: c++, templates

The following code is compiled with error msg:

```
    @> g++ test.cpp
    test.cpp: In member function 'void testit<E>::print()':
    test.cpp:79: error: 'COL' is not a class or namespace
    test.cpp:83: error: expected `;' before 'b2'
```

If I use COL::columns; to access static member, it wont compile successfully.
instead, access static member by SelectColumn::SELECT_COLS::columns; will be oK!

```
struct AllColumns
{
    static const char columns[];
};
const char AllColumns::columns[] = "*";

struct MemoryColumns
{
    static const char columns[];
};
const char MemoryColumns::columns[] = "data,data_expire_time";

template<typename E>
struct SelectColumn
{
public:
    typedef unsigned BIGT;
    typedef AllColumns SELECT_COLS;
};

template<>
struct SelectColumn<int>
{
public:
    typedef int BIGT;
    typedef MemoryColumns SELECT_COLS;
};

template<typename E>
class testit
{
public:
    typename SelectColumn<E>::SELECT_COLS COL;
    typename SelectColumn<E>::BIGT BIG;

    void print()
    {
      string str_a = COL::columns; //compile error here!
      string str_b = SelectColumn<E>::SELECT_COLS::columns; // OK

      BIG b2 = 10; //compile error here!
              typename SelectColumn<E>::BIGT b = 12; // OK
    }
};
```

How to fix it if I want to use COL::columns ?
thanks!

Comment: If you really want to access a static member via an instance of your class, be aware that this is bad style, since a reader might guess that it isn't static. To make your code *self-documenting*, always access static variables using the `type::name` syntax, not `instance.name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typename SelectColumn<E>::SELECT_COLS COL;
```

is a variable declaration, not a type.  (The name of the variable is `COL`, the type is `typename SelectColumn<E>::SELECT_COLS`)

Perhaps you meant to say

```
typedef typename SelectColumn<E>::SELECT_COLS COL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
typename SelectColumn<E>::SELECT_COLS COL;
```

`typename` used here is not a syntax to make `COL` an alias of `SelectColumn<E>::SELECT_COLS`, but to tell the parser that the identifier `SELECT_COLS` is a type and not a variable.

```
 str_a = COL::columns;
```

The reason why you got an error at this line, is because you are trying to access a member data of the`COL` object using wrong syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`COL` is an object, not a type, as such you must say `COL.columns` to accees members of it.

Comment: `columns` is a static member. While it is syntactically correct to write `COL.columns`, a reader might assume that this accesses an instance variable, so it should be considered *bad style*.